# Get session id when creating

Tags: php, session

I am creating authorization. In session i want to keep users id, but theoretically i can open session file on my pc and change this id and sand to  the server. So i want to create some extra security key from session id + my id in md5, but when i trying to get session id `$security_key = session_id($_SESSION['user_id']);` i get:

> Warning: Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal
>   characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on
>   line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please
>   verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
>   (/Users/Sites/demo/sessions/) in Unknown on line 0

**UPDATE: Thanks a lot, but just solved by myself. The correct version session_id(user_id)**

Comment: not all characters are allowed within the session id. For example, the file session handler only allows characters in the range a-z A-Z 0-9 , (comma) and - (minus)! , can that be your issue...?

Comment: session_id($_SESSION['userid']) - the same shit...

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to create a session token, simply use something like:

```
$_SESSION['token'] = md5(session_id().$_SESSION['user_id'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'randomlol');
```

If you're worried about somebody changing session variables on your host, you should look into storing your session variables in a database using a session handler.

Comment: no, only from user side. But the essence of the idea is that instead of randomlol i use session id, which is random and big and lives only for session time and also unique for every session.

Comment: I added the session id to my example. Although, you need to be careful if you're using session_regenerate_id();